# How should I trim spent flowers from a sun star (Ornithogalum dubium)?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, flowers, pruning

I've read several online guides about taking care of sun star, [*Ornithogalum dubium*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornithogalum_dubium), plants, but I'm confused about how to trim off the spent flowers. The instructions say to "remove spent flowers from the base, and another guide says to gently pull them out (and that it wouldn't harm the plant).

[image]

I can easily pull the individual spent flowers out of the spike:

[image]

Or am I supposed to pull the entire thing out of the plant? I tried to *gently* pull one of them out (one without any flowers on it) but it wouldn't budge. Should I be cutting the entire spike off? How do I trim the spent flowers here?

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to remove the whole spike, but with your flower already coming into full bloom it should not be giving you to much effort in removing. It does not so much pull like a weed, but it should be dry at the base and kinda snap off, like pull a length of celery off the stock. It will however die off on it's own in a month or two if you are unsure of whether or not the stock is from last year.